# Passing to separate arrays to the parameters of a constructor or method

Tags: java

When two arrays are passed to this constructor how do you access each individual element of each array. I'm only getting an object reference ( [I@1befab0 ) printed out.
Regards
Joe

```
  public class ConstParameters {


public ConstParameters(){
    }
  public ConstParameters(Object ob1, Object ob2){
     System.out.println("this is a constructor");
       System.out.println(ob1+"\n"+ob2);

  } 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Comment: What's your question? Array access expressions? Or casting?

Comment: Well you've got to declare the method parameters as array types... or cast to array types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either use this

```
public ConstParameters(Array[] ob1, Array[] ob2){
     System.out.println("this is a constructor");
       System.out.println(ob1+"\n"+ob2);

  }
```

or downcast your object like

```
int[] obj1= (int[])ob1;//but make sure it is castable otherwise it will throw classcast Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays utility class in Java:

```
Arrays.toString(Object[] arrayOfObjects);
```

This will give you a simple String representation of the Array.

As others have said, your parameters don't seem to be of Array types so your constructor should look something like this:

```
public ConstParameters(Object[] ob1, Object[] ob2)
```